# Powershell GUI to capture Date & Time to Variable

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This code open GUI to Input Time & Date:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Main Form
$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Consolas”, 13)
$mainForm.Text = ” Pick Time Frame”
$mainForm.Font = $font
$mainForm.ForeColor = “White”
$mainForm.BackColor = “DarkOliveGreen”
$mainForm.Width = 300
$mainForm.Height = 200

# DatePicker Label
$datePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$datePickerLabel.Text = “date”
$datePickerLabel.Location = “15, 10”
$datePickerLabel.Height = 22
$datePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($datePickerLabel)

# MinTimePicker Label
$minTimePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$minTimePickerLabel.Text = “min-time”
$minTimePickerLabel.Location = “15, 45”
$minTimePickerLabel.Height = 22
$minTimePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($minTimePickerLabel)

# DatePicker
$datePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$datePicker.Location = “110, 7”
$datePicker.Width = “150”
$datePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$datePicker.CustomFormat = “dd/MM/yyyy”
$mainForm.Controls.Add($datePicker)

# MinTimePicker
$minTimePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$minTimePicker.Location = “110, 42”
$minTimePicker.Width = “150”
$minTimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$minTimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
$minTimePicker.ShowUpDown = $TRUE
$mainForm.Controls.Add($minTimePicker)


# OD Button
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = “15, 130”
$okButton.ForeColor = “Black”
$okButton.BackColor = “White”
$okButton.Text = “OK”
$okButton.add_Click({$mainForm.close()})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($okButton)

[void] $mainForm.ShowDialog()


$datePicker | select value
```

Current Output:

**9/30/2021 12:59:34 PM**

Desired Output:

**After Selecting New date in GUI, it outputs New date only but not new Time.**
-> Require help to get Both GUI selected Date & Time .

Comment: Try changing `$datePicker | select value` to `($datePicker).Value.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')`

Comment: i need to capture New Time & Date from GUI not Date format change. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  You can get both items by doing something like this: `"$($datePicker.Text) $($minTimePicker.Text)"`, which will output something similar to: `10/03/2021 12:02:12`

Comment: Seriously this much , i totally missed ($minTimePicker.Text).   Thank you for help !